# How to ignore the .xml documentation files for reference .dll in Sandcastle

Tags: visual-studio, chm, sandcastle

I have a project targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2

I checked the `XML documentation file` checkbox in `Build` tab, allowing me to document my own code.

I then built the `.chm` file using Sandcastle Help File Builder GUI. All is well so far.

Now I added some functionality using `Tuples` and since I target framework version `4.5.2` and not later where it's included, I added the `System.ValueTuple.dll` reference.

Now the problem starts: in my release catalog, apart from my `doc.xml` file containing my summaries and whatnot for the code, there is a `System.ValueTuple.xml` containing documentation for the `.dll` file. However, after trying to rebuild the Sandcastle file after some changes, the following error appeared:

```
> SHFB: Error BE0065: BUILD FAILED: Tag początkowy „p” w wierszu 1241 na 
pozycji 2 nie pasuje do tagu końcowego „th”. wiersz 1241, pozycja 92.
   w System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   w System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowTagMismatch(NodeData startTag)
   w System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement()
   w System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   w System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   w System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   w System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   w System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
   w SandcastleBuilder.Utils.BuildEngine.XmlCommentsFile.get_Comments()
   w SandcastleBuilder.Utils.BuildEngine.XmlCommentsFile.get_Members()
   w SandcastleBuilder.Utils.BuildEngine.XmlCommentsFileCollection.get_ContainsInheritedDocumentation()
w SandcastleBuilder.Utils.BuildEngine.BuildProcess.Build()
```

The first line reads `Starting tag "p" in line 1241, position 2 does not match end tag "th" line 1241, position 92.`

After some quick lookaround I found that indeed it's the documentation file for `System.ValueTuple.dll` that's broken (and badly so). Since I don't really need it in my help file, and don't feel like fixing a hundred errors, how do I tell Sandcastle to ignore it?

So far I tried:

- Manually removing the file from `Release` catalog
- Adding `AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions` in `.csproj` file
- Checking/unchecking various fields in `Visibility` tab in Sandcastle project properties including the API Filter (the offending .dll is not there)

Google also returns me nothing, although I may be trying wrong search terms.

Answer (score 0):

As a test I added a NuGet package PdfSharp.dll to a small c# project. The resulting documentation was a 4.5 MB CHM file.

So, from the Sandcastle Help File Builder GUI's Solution Explorer I did a right click and removed the PdfSharp.dll and PdfSharp.xml [like shown in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irwsN.png). The resulting CHM has a size of 122 KB.